# Google O-Auth stops working after shifting from http to https

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I had created a web application in Django,setup Google and Facebook O-auth(using `python-social-auth`) for login and hosted it on a domain - `example.com`.Many users had already registered on it using google sign in.However yesterday I setup ssl certificates for my website and upgraded to an `https` connection.Thereafter I went to the console.developers.google.com and changed the  Authorized JavaScript origins to https://example.com and Authorized redirect URIs to https://example.com/soc/complete/google-oauth2/.Now oauth is working for new users however the old users are getting an error with error code 400(redirect_uri_mismatch) with the following message-

> The redirect URI in the request,does not match the ones authorized for
>   the OAuth client.

I am guessing this is because the tokens created for the users had an http endpoint.How do I refresh those tokens to point to the new https url without creating any hassle for the existing users?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple URLs for redirect URl and origin, so simply make sure you've configured both http and https variants.